# Печать документов из контейнера docker на локальном принтере

Tags: ubuntu, docker, cups

Есть винда, на которой я включил подсистему linux и установил Ubuntu.
Задача:
Развернуть контейнер на убунту, который может отправлять задания на печать из контейнера
Гугл говорит, что чтобы была доступна печать на Ubuntu надо развернуть cups.
Я развернул, добавил принтер, тестовая печать работает
Вопрос, как, и вообще возможно ли отправить из контейнера команду на хост машину,чтобы можно было распечатать документ?

Answer (score 0):

Ваш хост виден в контейнере по адресу гейтвея локальной сети. Выполните внутри контейнера команду `ip addr`:

```
$ ip addr
202170: eth0@if202171: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.2/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

У меня сеть `inet 172.17.0.2`, значит хост доступен по адресу `172.17.0.1`

По умолчанию CUPS поднимает сервер на порту locahost:631. Чтобы этот сервер стал доступным для докера, нужно поправить конфигурационный файл. В примере ниже даются широкие разрешения, вы можете посмотреть документацию по CUPS чтобы их адаптировать под ваши настройки

```
sudo vim /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
```

Слушать порт 631 на всех интерфейсах

```
# Only listen for connections from the local machine.
# Listen localhost:631
Listen 0.0.0.0:631
Listen /run/cups/cups.sock
```

Разрешить подключения от всех клиентов

```
# Restrict access to the server...
<Location />
  Order allow,deny
  Allow all
</Location>
```

Теперь как этим пользоваться.

Внутри докера установите пакет `cups-client`. Этот пакет содержит команду `lp` - клиент сервера CUPS.

У меня на хосте установлен пакет `cups-pdf`, который создаёт для CUPS pdf-принтер с именем `PDF`. Команда ниже печатает текущую дату в PDF файл:

```
/ # date | lp -h 172.17.0.1:631 -d PDF -U user
request id is PDF-14 (0 file(s))
```

Что тут написано:

- `-h 172.17.0.1:631` - печатать через хостовый принт-сервер
- `-d PDF -U user` печатать в принтер `PDF` от имени пользователя `user`.

Пользователя указывать необязательно. Я его указываю для принтера PDF, чтобы распечатки складывались в мой каталог на хосте `/home/user/PDF`

После выполнения этой команды на хосте появился файл `/home/user/PDF/stdin___lay_PDF-job_14.pdf`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примеры выполнены для контейнера на базе `alpine` и хоста Ubuntu-18

Comment: Сделал всё что было описано, не работает.
ip addr возвращает: 
686: eth0@if687: ..........
    inet 10.0.0.138/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eth0
690: eth1@if691: ..........
    inet 172.22.0.4/16 brd 172.22.255.255 scope global eth1

Попробовал ip eth0, eth1. Ничего не работает
lp -h 172.22.0.1:631 -U maks -d PDF возвращает No such file or directory, -h 10.0.0.1:631 просто зависает
Может быть надо с настройкой сети поколдовать?

Comment: Вариант с `172.22.0.1:631` выглядит многообещающе. Похоже именно на этом интерфейсе находится хост. Разрешите печатать на принтере `PDF` нелокальным пользователям: `lpadmin -d PDF -o printer-is-shared=true`

Comment: Нет, к сожалению не помогает. В любом случае спасибо за наводку, буду искать решение в этом направлении.

Comment: Может быть ещё какие-то настройки есть в cupsd.conf? Из контейнера пытаюсь выполнить команду curl 172.22.0.1:631, получаю ошибку curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.22.0.1 port 631: Connection refused. А если пытаюсь получить данные с 3000 порта, то всё получается

Comment: @Максим Проверьте файервол: `sudo ufw status`. Если он активен, добавьте исключение `sudo ufw allow 631/tcp`. Проверьте на каких адресах слушают порт 631: `sudo netstat -nplt | grep :631`. Рестартуйте сервер `sudo service cups restart`.